# How to connect PhoneGap application to internet

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, phonegap

I am coding applications using PhoneGap. In my apps I want to load  sources from online using `src="url"` e.g. pictures, texts or the google reCHAPTA. Testing it in my browser it works perfectly fine but on my smartphone, as an app, the pictures won't load.

Can anyone help me? Do I have to install a plugin? If so, how?

I haven't found any help online yet... :(

```
<img src="https://www.____.de/___/" alt=""/>
```

That's all I need, but the picture won't load when compiled into an android application.

No error message...

Comment: You might need to whitelist any domains you're using. It's been a while since I've worked with PhoneGap, but this resource might be helpful to you: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

you have to add plugin whitelist

open project parent folder in command prompt and run

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Hope it helps!